# Matlab: Number of observations per year for very large array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a large array with daily data from 1926 to 2012. I want to find out how many observations are in each year (it varies from year-to-year). I have a column vector which has the dates in the form of:

19290101
19290102
.
.
.

One year here is going to be July through June of the next year.

So 19630701 to 19640630

I would like to use this vector to find the number of days in each year. I need the number of observations to use as inputs into a regression.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell whether the dates are stored numerically or as a string of characters; I'll assume they're numbers.  What I suggest doing is to convert each value to the year and then using `hist` to count the number of dates in each year.  So try something like this:

```
year = floor(date/10000);
obs_per_year = hist(year,1926:2012);
```

This will give you a vector holding the number of observations in each year, starting from 1926.

Comment: This works, but I forgot to mention that one year here is June to July, of next year. Any thoughts? So from 19260701 to 19270630. Thank you

Comment: `hist( date, datenum( 1926:2012, 7, 1 ))`

Comment: Ok, how about this: `year = floor((date-700)/10000)`

Comment: both of these return (0 0 0 rows of array)

Comment: By `date` in the code I suggested, I meant your column vector of dates.  (You never specified what to call it.)  If you just type `date` as written it calls some function and returns a value that wasn't intended.

Comment: I made a small error somewhere else. This method works.  Thank you, very much.

Answer (score 0):

Series of years starting July 1st:

```
bin = datenum(1926:2012,7,1);
```

Bin your vector of dates within each year with bin(1) <= x < bin(2), bin(2) <= x < bin(3), ...

```
count = histc(dates,bin);
```